# Please sort deleted answers to the bottom

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-answers, sorting

Having recently hit the 10k mark I have noticed that people delete answers fairly often.

I find that having to sift through all of the deleted answers in a list can be a bit annoying.  I feel it would be best to sort them to the bottom of the list so people don't have to be bothered with them.

Comment: I posted an answer on this, but then deleted it.  You'll have to wait a few months to find out what I said.

Comment: `:(` I wish I had my SO rep here.

Comment: Actually @Pesto, I see your post in my recent replies envelope.  Thanks a bunch: **"Quit your whining, jjnguy! Be a man! "**

Comment: On this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541821/how-to-simplify-my-statefull-interlaced-modal-dialogs-in-asp-net-mvc) question a lot of answers was removed by community(http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) bot, there are userfull information to me and I dont bkp because trusting that information will always available to me and community. Is possible, at least to question owner, keep deleted answers visible ?

Comment: @newway You should ask that as a new question here on Meta. I think it could be a good idea.

Comment: hi @jjnguy, i did it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146961/is-possible-at-least-to-question-owner-keep-deleted-answers-visible

Comment: @newway it looks like people disagreed with us. Sorry `:(`

Comment: Though I've gotten used to this on the full site (while I prefer to read answers oldest first), it is pretty annoying on the mobile site. Would love to be able to hide deleted posts on the mobile site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Overall, it doesn't bug me too much (it's sometimes humorous to read what gets deleted and the reasons why), but I don't see why they couldn't get pushed to the bottom. Seems to make sense if you think about how the Accepted Answer gets pushed to the top.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution would be to provide a toggle show/hide deleted posts, instead of messing with the sort order.

Oh, and I invite anyone that doesn't think this is a problem to visit the [main page of the SOFAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq-closed). Tons of deleted, out-of-date stuff there.

Comment: I like the ability to actually hide them, though I guess I've gotten used to it.