# Deleted answers should get sorted at the very bottom of the answer list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-answers, answer-order

Deleted answers should be shown at the bottom, always.

Now they get shuffled just as regular answers.

Comment: +1 cuz answers don't get deleted without reason. They get deleted because they are not nice or because they suck.

Comment: Or because after you posted it you saw another answer that was exactly the same and decided the world didn't need two.

Comment: Duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7505/please-sort-deleted-answers-to-the-bottom

Comment: @Koning: That is not always true.

Comment: I can already see my deleted **answers** on the bottom. I think both this and the other @cletus question mean "deleted **questions**" should be shown at the bottom. Even then, it should be an option.

Comment: I would still like them to be ranked, but always below same-scored answers. Putting them below lower-ranked answers isn't good i think.

Comment: @Cawas: No, I mean other's people deleted answers. People with more than 10k rep can see them.

Answer (score 14):

I agree with this definitely and I am almost certain it's been asked numerous times in the past. I hate having to go through the fuss of having to see all the deleted answers the way it is now. Most of the time I don't want to see them, and the few times that I would want to, I would like for them to all be in a single continuous area.

Answer (score 3):

OK, for mods and pseudo-mods (10k rep users) we now sort deleted answers to the bottom. All other user classes are unaffected.

Comment: Some time ago it was *mods* and *diamond-mods*, now we're demoted to *pseudo-mods*.

Comment: @georg the actual name in code happens to be `User.IsPseudoMod` which is what I was thinking of

Comment: Jeff: This is not completed, at least not for oldest/newest sort orders - it appears that only vote sort-order pushes the deleted answers to the end. See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background/3240522#3240522.

Answer (score 1):

If the answers were slugged as if they were in the negatives, that would be okay if you're viewing in the Votes mode.

Then you can just ignore the far end of the answers list and be done with their presence on that front.