# Please show deleted answers below non-deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleted answers should get sorted at the very bottom of the answer list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/deleted-answers-should-get-sorted-at-the-very-bottom-of-the-answer-list)

I would like to see deleted answers below non-deleted answers of the same score. So that the grey deleted answers won't disturb the view on a same-scored answer group.

Comment: I've always wanted this too.

Answer (score -2):

If a person deletes their answer, maybe they do it because they don't want other people to see it?

Comment: People >10K can still see them.

Comment: @Ongle It is not a matter of showing them, but rather the order in which they are shown. (Because they **are** shown. People with over 10k rep are able to see all deleted questions and answers)