# Don't shuffle deleted answers (for anyone, not just mods)

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, answer-order

I was rather surprised to discover somebody already brought up this [exact thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/deleted-answers-should-get-sorted-at-the-very-bottom-of-the-answer-list) and it was marked as complete. Jeff [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/deleted-answers-should-get-sorted-at-the-very-bottom-of-the-answer-list/51730#51730):

> for mods and pseudo-mods (10k rep users) we now sort deleted answers to the bottom. All other user classes are unaffected.

I assume by "unaffected" he means "they can't see deleted answers, so we don't even check". This isn't completely true -- I can see my own deleted answers, and they get shuffled with the other zero-vote answers. Shouldn't they be dropped to the bottom for all users, not just mods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent of this feature is to help mods, for whom *all* deleted posts are visible.

I'd say it is as-designed for your deleted posts to show up in the standard order, since they are only visible to you (and mods, etc).

Comment: But shouldn't it be the fact that they're deleted that pushes them to the bottom? Regardless of who might view them, they are deleted and therefore less important than non-deleted answers.