# Always show deleted answers last (at the bottom) on *every* tab

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, sorting, answer-order

I know there are a bunch of requests already in the same vein, and moreover they have also been marked as "status completed", probably by Jeff (for example see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51730/209972)).

However, **Software Monkey**'s comment there illustrates my problem perfectly, in that this feature has only been implemented for the **votes** tab. Why not implement this *really* useful feature for the **active** and **oldest** tabs as well? I can't tell you how irritating it is to see good (or at least non-deleted) answers interspersed with deleted ones, especially ones that contain spam or outright offensive language.

Was this an oversight (in which case a fix would be highly appreciated), or is there a good reason for restricting this feature to only one of the three tabs (unfortunately the tab I don't use)?

P.S. I know there are userscripts available to hide deleted answers, but that's not what I'm requesting here.

Comment: Two years and absolutely no response from the team stating yes or no... who should we prod?

Comment: @Robotnik: Wish I knew. Looks like no developer cares to respond and like you said it's been two years so I'm sure it'll never be fixed.