# Always display deleted answers below other answers - possible bug regression?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, deleted-answers, 10k-tools

5 years ago this question was asked: [Deleted answers should get sorted at the very bottom of the answer list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/deleted-answers-should-get-sorted-at-the-very-bottom-of-the-answer-list), which was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). However this doesn't seem to be the case, at least not on Arqade. Take [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226370/ive-completed-my-contracts-now-what) for example:

[image: The answer section showing 3 deleted answers out of 5]
[image: continuation of above]

---

When viewing the answers in the 'oldest' tab (or even the votes tab when I had not voted it up), the deleted answers are taking precedence over Nick T's answer.

Is this still considered a bug, or was there a change in the policies of how we view/handle deleted answers?

Comment: As Emarkul [answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261527/140505) - that is due to how you are sorting the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're sorting by oldest first, which doesn't factor in answer deletion.

Try sorting by "votes" or "active," and it'll show up with deleted content at the bottom.

Comment: I've done that, which is why I said: *"When viewing the answers in the 'oldest' tab (or even the votes tab when I had not voted it up), the deleted answers are taking precedence over Nick T's answer"*

Comment: @Robotnik Votes tab is not reproducible for me anywhere I can see deleted answers. Oldest tab is definitely intentional.

Comment: Perhaps it is only prevalent on older sites: I can reproduce it on Arqade which is the only place I have >10k