# Has the sort order of deleted answers been changed intentionally?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, sorting

I was going to request that deleted answers always be placed at the end of the answers list for the people that can see them, when I came across this post which is marked "status-completed": [Deleted answers should get sorted at the very bottom of the answer list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20601/273494)

On the sites where I can see deleted posts, it appears they are currently sorted without regard for their deleted status and interleaved with answers that aren't deleted. I noticed it on questions on English Language Learners when sorting with "active" or "oldest" view, like [She {looks/is looking/looking} worried about something?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/she-looks-is-looking-looking-worried-about-something) where new answers are coming in on older questions. It appears that the answers are sorted to the bottom when "votes" is the selected order.

Was this regression intentional?

Comment: As far as I remember deleted answers always sorted according to the requested sort order. I wasn't "born" yet in 2009 and if I was I lacked the privilege to watch deleted posts.

Comment: @rene no they were always below all other answers. They're sorted **among themselves** by the requested sort order.

Comment: No repro here, tried in sandbox. Maybe it only happens with self answers? They always appear on top, think that even when deleted.

Comment: They are still sorted to the bottom for me. That sorting only applies to the Votes view, though. Not the Active and Oldest views.

Comment: @animuson the Active and Oldest views place deleted answers in between non deleted? Nice, never really seen it, as I never use those views. :)

Comment: @animuson That's it - I didn't check sorting by votes...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any regression here. It is by-design that the sorting of deleted answers to the bottom only occurs for the Votes sort type. The Active and Oldest sort types have never sorted to the bottom, at least according to the history of the code. The only sort alteration that applies to all three sorting methods is pinning the accepted answer to the top.

Comment: Would it make sense to update the old question to reflect that it is only for one view? I'm assuming that maybe a decade ago that was the only view?