# Give users the option of whether deleted answers are visible

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

Users with sufficient reputation can see even deleted answers and questions.  Many feel that these simply get in the way and/or would rather respect the author's wishes when the author deletes an answer. Similar to the ability to filter out questions based on tags, I suggest a setting in the profile that would allow such a user to choose whether deleted answers, other than their own, are visible or not.

I would exempt a person's own answers since it can be handy in certain situations to be able to delete, edit, then undelete your own answer.  One example is keeping an answer based on a misunderstanding from accruing downvotes while you are fixing it.

Comment: On this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541821/how-to-simplify-my-statefull-interlaced-modal-dialogs-in-asp-net-mvc) question a lot of answers was removed by community(http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) bot, there are userfull information to me and I dont bkp because trusting that information will always available to me and community. Is possible, at least to question owner, keep deleted answers visible ?

Answer (score 8):

I can see how it would be useful, but I think it would probably be easier to implement auto-sorting of the deleted answers to the bottom, no matter what their score was before they were deleted. This would push all the deleted ones down to the very bottom (and therefore on the very last page of any multi-page questions. It would make it a lot easier to ignore them then.

Comment: This question is a feature request to sort deleted answers to the bottom: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7505