# Ordering of deleted answers among others

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please sort deleted answers to the bottom.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7505/please-sort-deleted-answers-to-the-bottom)

Currently deleted answers (visible to users with 10k+rep) are shown in order as if they are regular answers (i.e. if they have more upvotes than not-deleted answers, they still show above them)

Example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465041/run-jsp-in-eclipse-on-specific-port-and-ssl/2468482)

I think, as they are deleted, they can be shown at the bottom (ordered by votes among themselves, if there are more than one deleted answer).

Comment: I'd rather see them above extremely-negative answers (-8 and beyond, but even many -3 to -8), as they're probably more useful.  (In other words: I've noticed the same issue, but don't see your suggestion as an improvement.)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7505/please-sort-deleted-answers-to-the-bottom