# Consider deletion when sorting answers by votes

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, sorting

Possible duplicate of [Please sort deleted answers to the bottom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7505/167443) (except that it is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)):

When sorting answers by votes, a deleted answer might show up before an undeleted answer with the same number of votes.

[image]

They've got the same score (and are from the same user), but one has been deleted because it's wrong. It should not be displayed before the non-deleted answer.

**Note:** Tagged as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) rather than [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) because the linked feature request is marked as completed, so this seems to be a bug with the implementation of that.