# Active sorting should put deleted answers at bottom

Tags: bug, answers, deleted-answers, sorting

Currently, active sorting ignores that posts are deleted, unlike other sorts.

[image]

According to [Please sort deleted answers to the bottom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7505/161344), the sort was fixed to sort deleted at the bottom, which applies for votes, and oldest sort, but somehow it doesn't apply to active sorting. I think that sorting should be consistent in that the removed posts are at bottom, no matter how the question is sorted.

Comment: I disagree. If you're sorting by active, you want to know what bumped the post. If it was an answer subsequently deleted, that should still be at the top. Otherwise how would you know?

Comment: @mhlester Even when sorted by votes, this happens.

Comment: Sure @Emracool. When you sort by votes, you're looking for good answers. Deleted answers generally aren't very good. Therefore they should be on the bottom in that view

Comment: Does this still happen? IIRC, there was a change sometime in the last few years to always sort deleted answers after all non-deleted answers...