# Own deleted answer sometimes showing above non-deleted answers with same score

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers, sorting

Consider the following SO post: [Can I treat a subquery with one row and one column as a scalar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417041/). Currently, I see my deleted answer to that post sometimes sorting above non-deleted answers (varies on each refresh):

> [image]

I suspect that this isn't supposed to happen, given that [Please sort deleted answers to the bottom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7505/) and [Deleted answers should get sorted at the very bottom of the answer list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20601/) were marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) back in the time of the dinosaurs.

In case it matters, I have less than 10k rep on SO at this time.

Comment: I just saw the same thing for one of my posts on Mathematics the other day.

Comment: I saw this as well recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51730/13):

> OK, for mods and pseudo-mods (10k rep users) we now sort deleted answers to the bottom. All other user classes are unaffected.

Comment: Is there a reason for that, though? It seems weird and inconsistent to me.

Comment: Yes. The reason the "sort deleted answers to the bottom" feature was added was that 10k users could potentially see lots of deleted answers, and this sorting order keeps deleted answers out of the way. But as a non-10k user, the only deleted answer you see is your own (or, alternatively, you own the question, in which case all answers are deleted and the sort-by-deleted is redundant). Dropping only your answer to the bottom doesn't provide any usability advantages.

Comment: Okay, I guess that's reasonable. (The inconsistency still bugs me, though.)